# Is Firebase Cloud Messaging safe for to restrict a login API?

Tags: rest, security, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have an API that must be restricted to our applications only, so no one else can use them in other applications.

The idea is using Firebase Cloud Messaging as a communication channel. We send a login request message to the server using Firebase Cloud Messaging, which returns a token generated in our server to the client. After that, the communication between the client and the server API is made directly using that token in HTTPS requests.

Is that a safe procedure for restricting our API use, or there are any vulnerabilities/flaws in it? If so, there is any way to improve that flow to make that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In general, FCM is *not* used in this use-case. It's commonly used for push notifications. I think you're need is more *auth* centered. So, using FCM here, is a no go.

> *We send a login request message to the server using Firebase Cloud Messaging, which returns a token generated in our server to the client.*

If you're gonna use FCM with this flow, you're gonna have to go through:

1. Registration for the client.
2. Send an upstream message.
3. Your server processes the message.
4. Your server sends a downstream message.
5. Client processes the message (in this case a token.

I think this would be a lot of work and is kinda necessary. I haven't dabbled too much in [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), but I think, maybe, [creating custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) is what you're looking for.